# Why do we use PQ and PV buses when solving a power flow equation?

Tags: power

It seems like it would be much easier to just use the admittance matrix and measured voltages to find all the currents and then just use that to get all the power flows. Why not this instead of the PV, PQ iterative solution using Newton Raphson?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do both.  Taking measurement data (voltages, flows etc.) from part of the system we run state estimation solvers to find a solution for the system.  See if [this helps](https://www.kth.se/social/upload/518a08d3f27654786295ca51/Lecture_15_StateEstimation.pdf).

Offline load flows are very useful for system planners.

Comment: That's a great high level overview of state estimation, thanks. Didn't realize we did both, probably based on what data is available right?

Comment: The operations folks want to know if they are operating the system at or near a vulnerable condition.  That is where the state estimator folks come in - they run frequently and then look for violations (overloads etc.). See terminology section [here](https://www.nerc.com/comm/PC_Reliability_Guidelines_DL/Reliability_Guideline_Methods_for_Establishing_IROLs.pdf). [Here is](http://relayman.org/papers/RealTimeScada2007.pdf) a paper about a project that uses state-estimator data to see if any protective relays may be near tripping on load.  The system planners run lots of load flows offline.